# Can't open recently downloaded textures: "Cannot read...no such file or directory"

Tags: file-format, error

I recently bought the new updated textures from textures.com (cgtextures), and after more than an hour of intense download and sorting the textures, i get this annoying message:

"Cannot read '//....\Desktop\Trabajos Blender\Do Widzenia\Blender\Biblioteca del Blender\Texturas, Materiales\Texturas de páginas random\Metales, industriales, engranajes, etc\Plástico, polímero, goma, etc\Plastic polymer\TexturesCom_Plastic_Polymer_1K_albedo.tif': No such file or directory"

Another thing is that every textures i recently downloaded are marked as 0b files instead o 777kib or 1.5mib or such.

What's happening and how i can solve this?

Comment: Is it possible that you ran out of disk space during the download or 'sorting'? Sounds like they could have been corrupted if they're showing as zero bytes in size.

Comment: The thing is that they're not corrupted, i can still open the images and use them on other softwares. The thing is that i could open 1 when it was in the download folder, but when i moved it to the textures folder i couldn't use them.

Comment: Perhaps it’s a problem with your path. Also there are commas and accented characters that could be causing a problem. It will be difficult for someone else to diagnose the problem since only you have access to it. Try moving them somewhere you know works (a simpler path) and prove that Blender can work with the files themselves and then move on from there one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you. I already solved the problem, i don't know what's the root problem, but i moved the folder out of that one with the other textures and it's now solved at all.

Comment: Great - glad it’s resolved. Please add an answer to your own question explaining your solution so you can then mark it as Accepted so others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Answer: I don't know why, but the folder where i saved the textures were bugged. Everything i save there becomes "corrupted", i mean, i can't use them at all (can open them on other softwares but they couldn't do anything), and also i couldn't use them as desktop background. The thing is that by moving the files from that folder to other folder far from it, the textures becomes safe to use, and the problem persists only in this folder while the other folders doesn't have this problem, this one can "corrupt" images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Windows includes limitations on the maximum file path to any accessible file - it appears that you have exceeded that limit.

See [docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file) - in particular the following section :

**Maximum Path Length Limitation**
*In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string`<NUL>`" where "`<NUL>`" represents the invisible terminating null character for the current system codepage.*

Your path (including the assumed 'c:\users\' prefix not shown) exceeds the 260 character limit. This means that when Blender (and other programs) attempt to access the files the file is effectively unreadable.

Since this is a limitation of the operating system (rather than a limitation of Blender) the only option is to relocate the files to a more O/S-friendly directory.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was that you need to copy downloaded file to 3D Objects map `C:\Users\<your username>\3D Objects` that worked for me